# R Dataframe: aggregating strings within column, across rows, by group

Tags: r, string, dataframe, aggregate-functions, string-concatenation

I have what seems like a very inefficient solution to a peculiar problem. I have text data which, for various reasons, is broken across rows of a dataframe at random intervals. However, certain subsets of are known to belong together based on unique combinations of other variables in the dataframe. See, for example, a MWE demonstrating the structure and my initial solution:

```
# Data
df <- read.table(text="page passage  person index text
1  123   A   1 hello      
1  123   A   2 my
1  123   A   3 name
1  123   A   4 is
1  123   A   5 guy
1  124   B   1 well
1  124   B   2 hello
1  124   B   3 guy",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

master<-data.frame()
for (i in 123:max(df$passage)) {
  print(paste0('passage ',i))
  tempset <- df[df$passage==i,]
  concat<-''
  for (j in 1:nrow(tempset)) {
    print(paste0('index ',j))
    concat<-paste(concat, tempset$text[j])
  }
  tempdf<-data.frame(tempset$page[1],tempset$passage[1], tempset$person[1], concat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  master<-rbind(master, tempdf)
  rm(concat, tempset, tempdf)
}
master
> master
  tempset.page.1. tempset.passage.1. tempset.person.1.                concat
1               1                123                 A  hello my name is guy
2               1                124                 B        well hello guy
```

In this example as in my real case, "passage" is the unique grouping variable, so it is not entirely necessary to take the other pieces along with it, although I'd like them available in my dataset.

My current estimates are that this procedure I have devise will take several hours for a dataset that is otherwise easily handled by R on my computer. Perhaps there are some efficiencies to be gained either by other functions or packages, or not creating and removing so many objects?

Thanks for any help here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two ways:

**base R**

```
aggregate(
    text ~ page + passage + person, 
    data=df, 
    FUN=paste, collapse=' '
)
```

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by_(~page, ~passage, ~person) %>%
    summarize_(text=~paste(text, collapse=' '))
```

Comment: `select` is not needed. What're `~` and `_` doing? Similarly, you don't need to subset `df` for `aggregate`. `data=df` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Check out `vignette('nse', package='dplyr')`

Comment: I chose this answer because it was marginally simpler and used base--though all the others worked just as well. Thanks all!

Answer (score 9):

**`data.table`** Here's one way:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[,.(concat=paste0(text,collapse=" ")),by=.(page,passage,person)]
#    page passage person               concat
# 1:    1     123      A hello my name is guy
# 2:    1     124      B       well hello guy
```

Putting the extra variables (besides `passage`) in the `by` doesn't cost much, I think.

---

**dplyr** The analogue is

```
df %>% 
  group_by(page,passage,person) %>% 
  summarise(concat=paste0(text,collapse=" "))

# Source: local data frame [2 x 4]
# Groups: page, passage, person
# 
#   page passage person               concat
# 1    1     123      A hello my name is guy
# 2    1     124      B       well hello guy
```

---

**base R** One way is:

```
df$concat <- with(df,ave(text,passage,FUN=function(x)paste0(x,collapse=" ")))
unique(df[,which(names(df)%in%c("page","passage","person","concat"))])
#   page passage person               concat
# 1    1     123      A hello my name is guy
# 6    1     124      B       well hello guy
```

Comment: nice answer, +1. one thing though: why not `DT[, .(concat=paste0(...` just so the data.table answer has an explicitly labeled column like the others?