# R data table group values into vector by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(j = c(3,8,9,11,10,28, 5), gr = c(9,9,9,9,10,10, 10), day = c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2)) 
  > dat
    j gr day
1:  3  9   1
2:  8  9   1
3:  9  9   2
4: 11  9   2
5: 10 10   1
6: 28 10   1
7:  5 10   2
```

I would like for each group (gr column) and day to create a **vector** with all the available values in j.

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
dat[, j[1:.N], by = .(gr, day )]
dat[, list(j[1:.N]), by = .(gr, day )]
```

This partially works but I would need to do some further manipulations to get the desired result:

```
dat[, list(list(Reduce(c, j, accumulate = T))), by = .(gr, day )]
```

My ideal result would look like:

```
> res_dat
   gr day all_values
1:  9   1        3,8
2:  9   2       9,11
3: 10   1      10,28
4: 10   2          5
```

I do not want this to be a string, I want it to be a **list of vectors** so this answer [data table string concatenation of SD columns for by group values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620877/data-table-string-concatenation-of-sd-columns-for-by-group-values) is not applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need a `list` column.  The `.(` is a concise syntax for `list(` in `data.table`.

```
dat[, .(j = .(j)), by = .(gr, day)]
```

-output

```
   gr day     j
1:  9   1   3,8
2:  9   2  9,11
3: 10   1 10,28
4: 10   2     5
```

---

i.e. it can be otherwise written as

```
dat[, list(j = list(j)), .(gr, day)]
   gr day     j
1:  9   1   3,8
2:  9   2  9,11
3: 10   1 10,28
4: 10   2     5
```

Comment: Will there be any speed difference between these two?